# ListView items aren't showing

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've looked around for various solutions but couldn't find anything that fixed the problem.

My listview layout (part of a larger layout):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Advantage"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvAdvLevel"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAdvLevel"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/etOneChar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Level"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listAdvantages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code to test populating it (from a fragment):

```
String[] strings = {"test 1", "test 2"};
ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listAdvantages);
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, strings));
```

The result (empty listview):

[image]

It does seem to resize with the number of array items it receives though. None of it is just showing up.

Comment: you use a cutom listView, look atbthis tuto it can help u , juste change the layout of the tem with yours , also apdute the object of datas to put in the listView

Comment: I already tried that with the same result. That's why I was testing to see if this simple setup would even work, and it's not.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think it is good practice to make `ListView` height as `wrap_content`. Try making it `match_parent`.
- Also specify the orientation as `vertical` in parent `LinearLayout` By default it is `horizontal` which is not what you want.

  ```
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:text="Advantage"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvAdvLevel"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvAdvLevel"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/etOneChar"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:text="Level"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listAdvantages"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </ListView>
  ```

Comment: That made it worse and now it doesn't seem to be showing up at all. http://i.imgur.com/onzcC5y.png?1?7927